# Criação do layout em Flutter

Tags: front-end, flutter, dart, layout

[image: Layout]

Estou tentando recriar um layout como este, de forma responsiva. Porém, só consigo chegar nisso:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Não tenho ideia de como vou chegar nesse resultado. Até agora, o que tentei foi isso:

```
    import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class HomeScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _HomeScreenState createState() => _HomeScreenState();
}

class _HomeScreenState extends State<HomeScreen> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Color(0xFF75b843),
      body: Center(
          child: Container(
        height: 450,
        width: 650,
        decoration: new BoxDecoration(
            color: Colors.white,
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
              topLeft: const Radius.circular(200.0),
              topRight: const Radius.circular(200.0),
              bottomLeft: const Radius.circular(200.0),
              bottomRight: const Radius.circular(200.0),
            )),
        child: Row(
          children: [
            SizedBox(
              width: 30,
            ),
            Container(
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
          image: DecorationImage(
            image: AssetImage("logo/splashscreenCopia.png"),
            fit: BoxFit.none,
          ),
          
        ),
        child: null
      ),
          ],
        ),
      )),
    );
  }
}
```

Mas não consigo fazer com o que o círculo fique desta maneira ou que a imagem se estique um pouco.

Comment: Use o widget Stack para sobrepor um ao outro, imagine eles como camadas e comece fazendo do fundo para frente.

Comment: Ok, mas acredito que meu maior problema seja reproduzir como na primeira print, um circulo não exato "pra fora" da tela

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Uma forma simples de fazer esse widget ser 'maior' que o tamanho disponível em tela é o `Transform.scale`. E pra deixar ele responsível, basta usar o `LayoutBuilder`.

Como aparentemente em sua imagem não é um círculo perfeito, parece ser meio um oval, utilizei também o `ClipOval`. Em resumo ficaria:

```dart
LayoutBuilder(
  builder: (BuildContext context, BoxConstraints constraints) {
    return Center(
      child: Transform.scale(
        scale: 1.05,
        child: ClipOval(
          child: Container(
            color: Colors.white,
            width: constraints.maxWidth,
            height: constraints.maxWidth - (constraints.maxWidth * 0.1),
            child: _CenterLogo(
              availableWidth: constraints.maxWidth,
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  },
);
```

Resultado:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Código completo abaixo, ou teste online acessando o [Dartpad](https://dartpad.dev/49d0595aa50be6ecc211cd6592d0b6c5?null_safety=true).

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      home: const _MyHomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class _MyHomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  const _MyHomePage();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Color(0xFF75b843),
      body: LayoutBuilder(
        builder: (BuildContext context, BoxConstraints constraints) {
          return Center(
            child: Transform.scale(
              scale: 1.05,
              child: ClipOval(
                child: Container(
                  color: Colors.white,
                  width: constraints.maxWidth,
                  height: constraints.maxWidth - (constraints.maxWidth * 0.1),
                  child: _CenterLogo(
                    availableWidth: constraints.maxWidth,
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          );
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}

class _CenterLogo extends StatelessWidget {
  const _CenterLogo({required this.availableWidth});

  final double availableWidth;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Stack(
      children: [
        Positioned(
          top: 1,
          bottom: 1,
          left: availableWidth * 0.2,
          child: Row(
            children: [
              Container(
                width: 80,
                height: 80,
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  color: Color(0xFF75b843),
                  shape: BoxShape.circle,
                ),
                child: Center(
                  child: Text(
                    'title',
                    style: TextStyle(
                      color: Colors.white,
                      fontSize: 30,
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              const SizedBox(width: 4),
              Text(
                'title',
                style: TextStyle(
                  color: Color(0xFF75b843),
                  fontSize: 30,
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Muito obrigado cara, de verdade. Mas ainda tenho uma duvida, porque quando mudo de `positioned` para `center` simplesmente alinha na esquerda ? Porque testando a responsividade o texto fica desalinhado com a tela.

Comment: Ele alinha à esquerda porque está dentro de um Stack. Utilizei um stack pois no seu exemplo de imagem ele não está alinhado ao centro, e sim um pouco para a esquerda. Mas aí você pode customizar como quiser.

Comment: Entendi, muito obrigado mesmo pela ajuda.